# Search regex expression whose line begins with

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Take for example these two lines:

```
# ManyRandomCharacters 1 2 3
ManyRandomDifferentCharacters 4 5 6
```

I'd like a regex such that it finds the numbers at the end but only for the line that doesn't begin with #. I just want to match the numbers, not the whole line (i.e., I just want "4", "5" and "6", not "1", "2" or "3"). That's the tricky part, because everything I tried selects all the line up to the numbers. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^` matches the start of the string, and if the multiline flag is set (depends on implementation, usually `m`), it detects also the start of a line.

So, something like `/^(?:[^#].*)(\d+ \d+ \d+)/gm` would match any line whose first character isn't `#`.